# Using Calculate Field tool to make empty field be populated with adjacent field's data?

Tags: arcmap, field-calculator

I have about 80 species of birds with at least about 100,000 records each. I used the iterator tool to create a field named [Count] for each species, but now need the empty field to be populated with the field that is next to it. The issue is the adjacent field is named after the species so I can't just select the field in the fields option of the calculator. If I went with that option, I would have to go through each species and have the empty field be equal to the species field. I just do not want to do this 80 times.

In the image, [ARTE] is the species code.

To clarify, I'm using ModelBuilder and have a iterator to go through and run several tools for me. I want to have it go through all of the species' attribute tables and populate the [Count] field with the field that is next to me. I will have more tools that are based on the [Count] field and do not think I can have the iterator look for 80 different field names. Just wanted to simplify it by having them all have the same field name.

[image]

Comment: This is a bit unclear. do you have a different table for each species, i.e.: 80 tables? if that is the case then the field calculator will not be able to complete this task. Also, if the value is exactly the same and the neighboring column, why not use that original column that already has the value?

Comment: I think I understand what you're after, a count of instances of each unique species. For this I would use summary statistics to create a table of count of unique species (statistic field OID, type COUNT, Case field ARTE - which doesn't appear to have values in your table) then join by attributes ARTE to ARTE and field calculate statistic_table.count_OID assuming your output table is called statistic_table.

Comment: @Marshall, yes I have a different table for each species. And it's because I still have many more steps in my model that will rely on my [Count] field.

Comment: I'm not sure I can have my model look for each species name in the model(?)

Answer (score 1):

Invest in Python, alternatively use batch mode in field calculator:

[image]

Yep, you'll need to enter field in 3rd column 80 times, use drag and drop for 1st column and Fill for second.